# Mypy: no signature inference?

Tags: python, type-inference, mypy

It looks like Mypy doesn't do anything to infer signatures. Is that correct? For example:

```
# types.py
def same_int(x: int) -> int:
    return x

def f(x):
    y = same_int(x)

    # This would be "Unsupported operand types for + ("int" and "str")" 
    # y + "hi"

    return y

f("hi")
f(1) + "hi"
```

No complaints when I do this:

```
mypy --check-untyped-defs types.py
```

Mypy will make inference about expressions within the body of `f` (if `--check-untyped-defs` is turned on). I'm wondering whether it would make sense to use that to also make and apply inferences about the signatures. (And if not, why not.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a deliberate design decision -- mypy was designed to allow you to mix together dynamic and typed code, mainly to make it easier to transition large and diverse codebases + allow you to selectively gain the benefits of both.

As a result, functions without type annotations are treated by default as dynamically typed functions and are implicitly given parameter and return types of `Any`.